# network is down for 5 min and up again for 3 min

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, netplan

I have started to see a very weird behavior on Ubuntu 20.04.4 (`5.4.0-121-generic`) when the network is going down for 5 minutes and then is up for 3 minutes.
The strange thing that when the **network is down** I see:

```
username@ws01u:~$ ifconfig eno1
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether I DELETED MAC  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17761  bytes 1796102 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10256  bytes 1288807 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7e00000-f7e20000
```

and I can't ping this machine from outside but can from this machine! RX packets are moving but TX are not.

After it is **up back** both ways are pinging and network is okay for any access:

```
username@ws01u:~$ ifconfig eno1
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::36e6:d7ff:fe24:9f6d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether I DELETED MAC  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18280  bytes 1848698 (1.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10522  bytes 1320094 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7e00000-f7e20000**
```

At this point ifconfig is starting to show static IP I set before and TX packets are activating also.

The `cat /var/log/syslog` is showing next information:

```
Jul  4 15:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <warn>  [1656949390.2327] dhcp4 (eno1): request timed out
Jul  4 15:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949390.2328] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul  4 15:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949390.2330] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 10:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <warn>  [1656949390.2367] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'netplan-eno1'
Jul  4 10:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949390.2376] device (eno1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 10:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949390.2546] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Jul  4 10:43:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949390.2546] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed timeout -> done
Jul  4 10:48:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949690.2327] policy: auto-activating connection 'netplan-eno1' (10838d80-caeb-349e-ba73-08ed16d4d666)
Jul  4 10:48:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949690.2343] device (eno1): Activation: starting connection 'netplan-eno1' (10838d80-caeb-349e-ba73-08ed16d4d666)
Jul  4 10:48:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949690.2348] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 10:48:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949690.2364] device (eno1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 10:48:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949690.2383] device (eno1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 10:48:10 ws01u NetworkManager[2301]: <info>  [1656949690.2395] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul  4 10:48:12 ws01u systemd-networkd[892]: eno1: Gained IPv6LL
```

First seven logs are when the network is down (`Jul  4 10:43:10`)
second few when it is up again (`Jul  4 10:48:10`) and last one.

netplan configured to receive `192.168.3.2`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your logs show DHCP activity, but you say "netplan configured to receive 192.168.3.2", which implies a static IP address. You can't do both. Also, replace the cable, and check the connector.

Comment: You're right, I forgot disable dhcp4 option in netplan configuration file. Thanks my friend.